# Boost build with gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, boost, c++20, abi

I use boost in my project and I need to build it from sources.

I use the gcc 11 as compiler ans I want to build the project using -std=c++20 option.

Do I need to build boost using -std=c++20 too?

Knowing that:
**Known Issues on boost**:

Boost.Operators is currently **incompatible with C++20** compilers, which in some cases may manifest as an infinite recursion or infinite loop in runtime when a comparison operator is called. The problem is caused by the new operator rewriting behavior introduced in C++20. As a workaround, users are advised to target C++17 or older C++ standard.

What can I do?

Comment: boost.operators is a *header-only library*. It need not be built separately. It is essentially a part of your project. If you build your project using c++20 and it uses boost.operators, then the known issue applies *to your project*.

Comment: Can I build Boost separately to generate static libs using -std=c++17?

Comment: Boost is not one library. It is a collection of libraries. Some of them need to be built separately. Others *cannot* be built separately, because they are header-only. Boost.operators is a header-only library. Goto comment 1.